# Passing javascript variables to rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, variables

Here is the problem i'm stuck on. I want to pass the javascript variables to the rails controller.

```
<script>
var mdate = "26 December 2013";
var phone = prompt('Enter your phone!');
if (phone) {
    //Passing mdate and phone variables to rails controller(book_date & phone)
}
else
{
    alert("Cancelled");
}
</script>
```

My controller

```
def new
        @booking = Booking.new
end
def create
    @booking = Booking.new(book_param)
    if @booking.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash[:notice_booking_failed] = true
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end

private
def book_param
    params.require(booking).permit(:id, :book_date, :phone)
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically you cant pass variables between two languages.

You can pass those values to rails controller by appending in url

```
<script>
var mdate = "26 December 2013";
var phone = prompt('Enter your phone!');
if (phone) {
    //Passing mdate and phone variables to rails controller(book_date & phone)
    window.open("localhost:3000//controller/create?mdate="+mdate+"&phone="+phone,"_self")
}
else
{
    alert("Cancelled");
}
</script>
```

In your controller

```
def create
    data = params[:date]
    phone = params[:phone]
    @booking = Booking.new(book_param)
    if @booking.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash[:notice_booking_failed] = true
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you configure your config/route.rb accordingly

More Info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks so much. I simply did `window.open("/controller/create?mdate="+mdate+"&phone="+phone,"_self")` and it worked for me. :)

Comment: You can easily pass data through a hidden field.

Comment: question is about how to pass JS variables to rails. Hidden field is not required here in anyway.

Comment: Hello shiva, is it required for those two fields (data, phone) to be inside the form? If yes then what should I give the controller name in **form_for** tag? In my situation I have member_code field and many buttons to create method of different controllers. I want to send member_code to respective controller each time a button (or link_to) is pressed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Ajax code in jQuery:

```
$("#submit_button").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
   event.preventDefault();

  /* get values from elements on the page: */
   var mdate = $('#mdate').val();
   var phone = $('#phone').val();

  /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
      url: "/BookCreate/?mdate="+mdate+"&phone="+phone,
      type: "post",
      data: values,
      success: function(){
        alert('Saved Successfully');
      },
      error:function(){
       alert('Error');
      }
    });
});
```

Routes : ( As I am assuming your controller name is book )

```
match '/BookCreate', to: 'book#create'
```

For this you have to add jquery file to your code or this link

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
$.post("/bookings?booking[phone]=" + phone + "&booking[book_date]=" + mdate)
```

It will go to `BookingsController#create` action with params hash:

```
{ booking: { phone: "entered from prompt", book_date: "26 December 2013" } }
```