# Passing a JS variable to a controller in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I found this: [Passing javascript variables to rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786831/passing-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller)

...and I have been trying to do the same thing i.e.

`window.open("http://localhost:3000//controller/index?location="+location,"_self")`

my controller:

```
class FindMeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    location = params[:location]
    @snake = Snake.where(location: location)
    if @snake.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

However, I always get a 'No route matches error'. I understand this is likely something simple but I am yet to understand how to fix it.

I tried changing the 'controller' in the window.open line to the actual controller name - 'find_me_controller' but that didn't work. I also tried omitting the localhost and just doing '/controller...' but that also didn't help.

Can someone explain what this error implies and how I can fix it.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Okay, I have added this to routes.rb:

get 'FindMeController/index', to: 'find_me_controller#index'

and the line is now 
`window.open("http://localhost:3000//FindMeController/index?location="+countryLoc+",_self")`

...but now I have a new error: uninitialized constant FindMeControllerController

Also, rake routes no gives:

FindMeController_index GET  /FindMeController/index(.:format) find_me_controller#index

EDIT2 :

I have destroyed the find_me controller and generated a snakes controller and copied in the old index action but now there are a load of errors there werent before. It says 'home/samuel/Code/VenomApp/VenomRails/app/controllers/snakes_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end' for my controller:

```
class SnakesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    location = params[:location]
    @snake = Snake.where(location: location)
    if @snake.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

which I dont understand. Why is it going to my controller and not my snakes#index view???

Comment: can you paste the actual url? i assume something like: http://localhost:3000/find_me/index?location="+location", _self

Comment: its this "http://localhost:3000//find_me_controller/index?location="+countryLoc+",_self"

Comment: can you try renaming your route to something else? Like this in config/routes.rb:                                                                                        get 'myfind' => 'find_me#index'                                                               and then try to access the action as myfind_path

Comment: Oh! as a matter of observation, the above code from your controller is missing one 'end' statement!!! The if-else doesn't have a matching 'end'! And this is true for both your edits: The FindMeController as well as your SnakesController :)

Comment: Ah, I noticed that. The reason I was trying to do this was because I wanted to use JS thinking it would be easier but it seems there are some gems which make geolocation easy so I will research them, This approach seems to be far more awkward - thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

change this    http://localhost:3000//controller/index?location="+location,"_self  to     "http://localhost:3000/controller/index?location="+location+",_self"

Comment: I just made a synax mistake that stopped it doing anything. The original problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try rake routes on console and find out rout for FindMecontroller's index action and replace that route i.e.

window.open("<%= your_path %>" + "/" + "your variables")

Comment: You need to add resource in your routes.rb file. As per the rails naming convention your controller name should be SnakesController and in your routes.rb file you need to add resources :snakes, then you will get snakes_path as an path for index action

Comment: so I should remove my find_me controller and make a new SnakesController?

Comment: got index action's route?

Comment: ? rake routes gives this: FindMeController_index GET /FindMeController/index(.:format) find_me_controller#index but I am not sure what you mean. Isn't it just FindMeController/index since I put it in routes,rb

Comment: I added 'resources :snakes' to my routes.rb but I don't think this helps me as my controller is called findme?

Comment: you just have to find correct path for index action

Comment: I am confused - what form is that path in? what will I have to put in the window.open line? is it to do with 'snakes' or 'findme'?

Comment: can you paste all your routes?