# Create url query params and pass to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem involves passing values from JS to controller and then using them to query and return some output data. These values are as a result of selections in the UI:

```
<!-- Select car make -->
<ul id = "make">
   <% Car.all.each do |c| %>
      <li><%= link_to c.make, todos_data_path(:make_id => c.id), :method => :post, remote: true %></li>
   <% end %></ul>

<!-- Select car body -->
<ul id = "body">
   <% Type.all.each do |t| %>
       <li><%= link_to t.name, todos_data_path(:body_id => t.id), :method => :post, remote: true %></li>
   <% end %></ul>
```

Extract the selected values in JS:

```
var make = $('#make').text();    
var body = $('#body').text();
```

After searching I learnt from a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786831/passing-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller) that one cannot pass variables from  JS to Rails directly. Instead, pass values to the controller by appending them as params in url. From my understanding what I need can be done in three basic steps:

Step 1: Create query string parameters using JavaScript. 
One way [way](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256) to do this:

```
var url = "http://www.myapp/todos/data?" + $.param({make_id: make, body_id: body})
//http://www.myapp/todos/data?make_id=4&body_id=3
```

Step 2:  Append the query string to the url.
Following an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786831/passing-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller) one can append the query string to url by:

```
window.open(url, "_self");
```

Step 3:  Run the url string and use params in the controller.

My routes:

```
resources : todos, only: [:index, :new, :create , :destroy]
get '/todos/data (:make_id)(:body_id)' => 'todos#data'
```

Controller:

```
def data
    @make = params[:make_id]
    @body = params[:body_id]

    @vehicles = Vehicle.where(make: @make, body: @body )

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ redirect_to root_path }
      format.js { }
    end
end
```

The output after running the string in the url:

```
Started GET "/todos/data?make_id=2&body_id=3" for 10.240.0.185 at 2017-05-24 12:55:58 +0000
Processing by TodosController#data as HTML
Parameters: {"make_id"=>"2", "body_id"=>"3"}
Redirected to http://myapp/
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

It seems that everything works fine up to the point where there is `redirect_to root_path`. I would like instead `format.js { }` executed since my aim is to render `data.js.erb`. How can I make the action respond to JS format instead of HTML? I tried specifying in the route `get '/todos/data(:make_id)(:body_id)' => 'todos#data', :defaults => { :format => 'js { }' }` but it generated unknown format error .

I have posted the whole process of what I am trying to do for clarity on what I want to achieve and maybe get suggestions on how to do the whole thing differently.

EDIT:
I need also to show my todo.js

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('#make').on('click', 'li', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#body').on('click', 'li', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are executing `window.open(url, "_self");`, it is requesting as a html get request. Why don't you use ajax?

```
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: "GET",
   dataType: "script", /*optional*/
   success: function(response){
    console.log(response)
   }
 })
```

Option 2:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.myapp/todos/data",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "script",
      data: { 
        make_id: make, 
        body_id: body 
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
      }
  });
  return false;
})
```

in the place of `$("a")`, use your desired selector.

Comment: I suspect the `ajax` does not run since nothing is logged to console. I even added `alert(response)` but no pop-up comes.

Comment: Did you mention dataType as js?

Comment: Yes, I did. This I put in the `data.js.erb`

Comment: I have edited my answer. That should work. Make sure the the `link_to` doesn't send the request to the server. Ajax should handle the request.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the output I was getting before. The output using the `ajax` after I hit one of the UI links to send a request is: `Started POST "/todos/data?make_id=2" for 10.240.1.45 
Processing by TodosController#data as JS
  Parameters: {"make_id"=>"2"}
  Rendering todos/data.js.erb
  Vehicle Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "vehicles".* FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."make" = $1 AND "vehicles"."body" = $2  [["make", "Saab"], ["body", "wagon"]]
  Rendered todos/_graph.html.erb
  Rendered todos/data.js.erb 
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)`

Comment: So the `GET "/todos/data?make_id=2&body_id=3"` is not hit. Let me try with your edit.

Comment: Well, you want to send a request combining two different parameters. You should use dropdown instead of links. Is that what you want?

Comment: I have tried the edit and in place of `//Do Something to handle error` I put `alert("Error!");`. I get no alert implying that the `$.ajax` was not executed. I could use dropdowns but it works with links since I used `$('.active').removeClass('active');` for each of the UI elements

Comment: you are not triggering the ajax.

Comment: The link has several options just like a drop-down via the `<% Car.all.each do |c| %`. Yes, I am not trigering ajax now. Other than the initial `POST` via the `remote: true`. But, the `window.open(url, "_self");` was being triggered

Comment: Tried the edit but doesnt seem to trigger ajax. I did  `$('#make').on('click', 'li', function (){  alert("tessst");    $.ajax({ ......`. Strange that the ajax (and alert) is not triggering even after clicking the element. However, the same `$().on(click)` works in the `todos.js` file. I have edited my post by showing what I have in the `todos.js`

Comment: I had an error in my `url:` attribute of `$.ajax` that made the ajax not to be triggered. Your suggestion works but I think you need to change the `dataType: 'script'` instead of `js` for your solution to pass as the answer